# Get first instance of text for parent item in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, text, beautifulsoup, parent-child

I have the following HTML:

```
<div>


  <h5>Item1</h5>
  $14.00<br>
  <br>

  <h5>Item2</h5>
  $16.29 (Shop Rite)<br>
  $15.49 (Costco)<br>
  <br>

  <h5>Item3</h5>
  ...
</div>
```

I am trying to organize this information into a list based on the item number, like such:

```
+--------+--------------------+
| Item1  | $14.00 (BJs)       |
| Item2  | $16.29 (Shop Rite) |
| Item2  | $15.49 (Costco)    |
+--------+--------------------+
```

I would like something similar to the following:

```
Items = []
if (BS.find('h5', text="Item1")):
  for content in BS.find('h5', text="Item1").parent:
    Price = BS.find('h5', text="Item1").parent.content[0]
    Items.append("Item1", Price)
```

My main goal is to be able to get the text separated by the `<br>` tags individually and then store that into a list called `Items` but I am not sure how to iterate through each of the `<br>` tags of the `<div>` tag based on the `<h5>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you collect the data that you collect in a dictionary-like object rather than a list, so that you can associate a number of prices with each header text. I've used a `defaultdict` with a `list` type.

Find the collection of `h5` elements first. Then find the collection of siblings for each of these. But notice that the second and third `h5` elements are siblings of the first, for instance, which means that, in processing siblings for any given `h5` we want to stop when we encounter *another* `h5`. We `break` when we see that. In a similar way when we encounter a `br` element we ignore that; we `continue` and carry on with the next sibling. Then also, if the sibling is empty but for white space we also ignore it.

Finally, an item that passes these tests is added to the dictionary.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('temp.htm').read(), 'lxml')
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> info = defaultdict(list)
>>> for h5 in soup.findAll('h5'):
...     for item in h5.next_siblings:
...         if item.name == 'br':
...             continue
...         if item.name == 'h5':
...             break
...         if not item.strip():
...             continue
...         info[h5.text].append(item.strip())
...
```

We can display the contents of the dictionary in this way. I leave it to you to format it appropriately.

```
>>> info
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Item1': ['$14.00'], 'Item3': [], 'Item2': ['$16.29 (Shop Rite)', '$15.49 (Costco)']})
>>> for item in info:
...     for price in info[item]:
...         item, price
...         
('Item1', '$14.00')
('Item2', '$16.29 (Shop Rite)')
('Item2', '$15.49 (Costco)')
```